# How to use different where conditions depending on the input parameter in procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to use different where conditions, which depends on input parameter in procedure.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_IF (IN param1 INT)  
BEGIN  
    SELECT * FROM articles 
    IF param1 = 0 THEN  
        WHERE name = 'Тест'
    ELSE  
        WHERE name = 'Проверка'  
    END IF;  
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `case when` when there are more than two conditions

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_IF (IN param1 INT)  
BEGIN  
    SELECT * FROM articles 
    WHERE name = 
    (
       CASE WHEN param1 = 0 THEN 'Тест'
       ELSE 'Проверка' END
    );
END
```

If there are only two conditions,then you can use `IF` instead

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_IF (IN param1 INT)  
BEGIN  
    SELECT * FROM articles 
    WHERE name = IF(param1 = 0,'Тест','Проверка');
END
```

Comment: If there is no else?

Comment: @VladimirGolub what do you mean by no else? If there is no else then you can just use `where` directly or check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785209/case-statement-within-where-clause-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: `SELECT * FROM articles IF param1 = 0 THEN  WHERE name = 'Тест'` , no else condition.

Comment: @VladimirGolub I think the better way is to create a dynamic sql or use some language framework to control it,such as `mybatis`,for dynamic sql(which I think is a bad practice),you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42383446/how-to-generate-dynamic-where-condition-in-mysql-procedure

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest avoiding `CASE` expressions in the `WHERE` clause in general.  You can use:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_IF (IN param1 INT)  
BEGIN  
    SELECT a.*
    FROM articles a
    WHERE (param1 = 0 AND name = 'Тест') OR
          (not param1 <=> 0);
END
```